# Reposition Date String to locale

Tags: javascript

I have a string representing january, 2nd 2013 (data) and need to have it rearranged to meet the german form which is "02.01.2013". Is there a more elegant and efficient way to rearrange it than my solution?

```
var data = '01.02.2013';
var result = data.split('.')[1]+'.'+data.split('.')[0]+'.'+data.split('.')[2];
console.log(result)
```

How could I use to .localeString("de-de")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
String.prototype.toLocaleString = function (locale) {
    if (locale == "de-de") return this.replace(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/, '$2.$1.$3');
}
console.log('01.02.2013'.toLocaleString("de-de")); // 02.01.2013
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/73peR/